# Largest positive integer $n$ that satisfies a given inequality

Tags: inequality

> Largest positive  integer value of $n$ in $$n \cdot \left(\frac{abc}{a+b+c}\right)\leq (a+b)^2+(a+b+4c)^2$$
>
> where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$.

---

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ We can write $(a+b)^2+(a+b+4c)^2= (a+b)^2+[(a+2c)+(b+2c)]^2$

Now Using $\bf{A.M}\geq G.M,$ We get $$\frac{(a+2b)+(b+2c)}{2}\geq \left[(a+2b)(b+2c)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

So $$(a+b+4c)^2\geq 4(a+2b)(b+2c)$$

So $$(a+b+4c)^2+(a+b)^2\geq 4(a+2b)(b+2c)+(a+b)^2$$

$$ = 4(ab+2b^2+2ac+4bc)+(a^2+b^2+2ab)$$

Now How can i solve after that, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Does $\mathbb{R^{+}}$ denote the positive reals or the nonnegative ones?

Comment: For positive real number.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such positive integer. Scaling $a$, $b$ and $c$ by the same factor $\lambda$ multiplies the left-hand side by $\lambda$ and the right-hand side by $\lambda^2$. Thus you can always rescale to violate the inequality for any positive $n$.

Comment: Sorry joriki, I have edited my question. So plz retake it.